# Is Cersei's Penance Walk partly inspired by the short story the Emperor's New Clothes?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

While I heard that Cersei's penance walk is loosely inspired by the penance walk of Jane Shore (which is a real event), the first thing that came to mind regarding the penance walk is the story from Hans Christian Andersen's short story that shows the emperor showing off his new "clothes" to the people when he is actually naked.

Is it more of a coincidence that Cersei's penance walk is similar to the emperor's walk in the short story?

Comment: Except for "clothless ruler" part these two have absolutely nothing in common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Public penance was fairly common in Medieval Europe. As it says [here](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35905):

> The practice of requiring penitents to give public satisfaction for
>   their sins as a condition for absolution and reconciliation with the
>   Church. In vogue up to the early Middle Ages, public penance could be
>   either solemn or not, depending on the gravity of the offense and the
>   amount of scandal given.
>
> When public penance was also solemn, the reason had to be a grave one.
>   Among the public crimes that might be subject to solemn penance, the
>   most common were adultery, apostasy, fornication, and murder,
>   including abortion. A historic example of public penance was Henry
>   II's walking barefoot in 1174 to the shrine of St. Thomas of Bucket,
>   to expiate his part in the murder of the archbishop. The more common
>   practice was to limit solemn penance to those crimes that gave such
>   scandal as seemed to call for proportionate expiation.
>
> More generally, public penance was not solemn. The person would
>   secretly confess some grave sin from which he was absolved by a
>   priest. His satisfaction would be an external penance from which
>   others might conclude the nature of the sin, but there was no formal
>   identification as a public sinner.

This real historical practice was almost certainly the inspiration for Cersei Lannister's "Walk of Shame". Since the point of the "Emperor's New Clothes" story was more about "Speaking Truth to Power", I doubt it has any connection here. I can kinda see what the OP is asking about though; certainly the "Emperor" ended up being publicly shamed, although that wasn't the moral of the story. There's also Lady Godiva's ride, but that was about her purposely shaming her husband into doing something (reducing taxes, IIRC). But neither of these really fits Cersei's *officially mandated punishment*.